# how exactly use and update the global variables in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am new to react-native. I wrote stop watch but the problem is that when I go to another page and then come back again the stop watch stop working. I want the stop watch keep working until the user press the stop button.I know, I should use global variable but I dont Know how to use it.here is my code:

```
export default class Record extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  stopwatchStart: false,
  stopWatchTime: '00:00:00'

};
toggleStopwatch() {

if (!this.state.stopwatchStart) {
  startDate = new Date();
  startTime = startDate.getTime();
  that = this;
  setInterval(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    time = (date.getTime() - startTime) / 1000;
    hour = parseInt(time / 3600);
    timeAgo = parseInt(time % 3600);
    min = parseInt(timeAgo / 60);
    second = parseInt(timeAgo % 60);
    that.setState({
      stopWatchTime: (hour + ':' + min + ':' + second)
    })
  }, 1000);  
}
this.setState({ stopwatchStart: !this.state.stopwatchStart });}
```

Comment: what do you mean by page ? are you closing application or are you going to another route inside of your application

Comment: I mean view. when I run the app on the emulator and then press the start button stopwatch works. but when I go to another view it stops working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to understand what do you need, so I have the following question, do you want the interval to continue running after you change the screen?, because the components do not work that way.
You must follow the life cycle of the components (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html), therefore, after you change the screen of the "Record" component, it will be unmount and the interval will destroy.
You may describe a little more what do you want to do with the interval, in case you want to use it in more than one component.

Comment: yes, exactly. I want the interval to continue running after I change the screen.

Comment: This time I recommend you using the following library as a guide https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer, because it is the closest thing to what you need.

Answer (score 2):

**I think you should use redux for handling this...**
https://redux.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what you mean by view but probably you are opening another app or taking app to background. To persist data in your React Native application you should use AsyncStorage. In future you might want to use Sqlite, Redux persist or something else like these ones to keep your data persistent.

You can set this before app goes to background.

```
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('timeKey', myTimeVar.toString());
} catch (error) {
  // Error saving data
}
```

And by using your key you can get the value of latest

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('timeKey');
  if (value !== null){
    // We have data!!
    console.log(value);
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

You don't have to run timer in background by doing simple extraction (appClosedTime-currrentTime+timeWastedInFirstSession) you can achieve your goal.